# Why does uniform initialization not work in this case?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, uniform-initialization

Why is it that in this case I cannot use uniform initialization of the member `thing` from variadic template parameters?

```
#include <random>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Test(Args... args)
        : thing { std::forward<Args>(args)... }
    {}
private:
    T thing;
};

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 mt { 42 }; //fine
    Test<std::mt19937> t1 { 42 }; //not fine
}

error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to
'std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32, 624, 397, 31, 2567483615, 11, 4294967295, 7,
2636928640, 15, 4022730752, 18, 1812433253>::result_type' (aka 'unsigned long') in initializer list
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1n141W

Comment: An `int` "narrowed" to an `unsigned long`? Please edit the post to include the compiler you used.

Comment: Did you try perfect forwarding the arguments? `: thing{ std::forward<Args...>(args)...}`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I am using Clang trunk, and I've added a link to godbolt.

Comment: @Casey I forgot to forward, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @DanielLangr I don't get it. It's perfectly fine to use uniform initialization on `std::mt19937` directly, as demontrated on godbolt

Comment: No, it's not: https://godbolt.org/z/x7f4z9.

Comment: Changing `42` to `42u` also fixes it.

Comment: gcc give only warning for it. https://godbolt.org/z/z1TfK3

Comment: @DanielLangr So you are telling me that even with std::forward the compiler doesn't recognize it as a constant expression? Why does this effect std::mt19937 and not other types I've tried (primitives, POD structs)?

Comment: @Chris_F it's not constant once it's pass as (non-constexpr) parameter.

Comment: But the parameter in `args` pack is not constant, right?

Comment: @DanielLangr OK, so function parameters are never a constant expression. Should have realized that. In that case I suppose the other question does answer this question.